How to Make my Module loaded automatically when PowerShell session starts
I created my module and now my goal is to load it automatically when PowerShell session starts, extra I like to have it for every user.
Based on some tutorials and this Microsoft Docu I copied all dir with my module to path:

C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\

Unfortunately my module is not not loaded successfully - I mean called function stored in this module is not recognized (Tested on Windows 11 24H2, PowerShell 5.1).
What for me is more unclear - If I simply list all available Commands in my module, then they all will be shown, and next called function again will be executed fine:

Also command "Get-Module" will display this time my module.
This is how my module looks like in Program Files dir:

Did I did something wrong, or not understand it?
The same result I got when I stored my TestModul in Local Profile dir ("$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules")
Until I query for all commands from my module, any of function there will be not recognized in current session of PowerShell.

The fact that Get-Command -Module <moduleName> works indicates that module auto-loading is not the problem.
A more likely explanation is that the manifest attached to your module does not explicitly list TestFunction as an exported command, and as a result PowerShell cannot make out the link between the two until after the module has been imported.
In your module manifest, make sure the FunctionsToExport key explicitly lists the exported function name, eg:
FunctionsToExport = @("TestFunction")

To update the existing manifest, use Update-ModuleManifest:
Update-ModuleManifest -Path path\to\TestModul_1.01.psd1 -FunctionsToExport TestFunction


Thanks. @Mathias R. Jessen. Seems its works better now. Before I had in my module manifest: FunctionsToExport = '*'. So its possible to have all functions exported with similar command or I have to declare it one by one in module manifest?

@MikeZetPL If you want command-discovery for modules not already imported, yes, you'll need to explicitly list all exported commands. It's also a healthy practice to get into to avoid "leaking" internal functions you didn't mean to export :)
